# Mongodb create auto creat index task every month

Tags: mongodb

I have a Linux server with a Mongodb database.

Our collections are created by month. We have a new task is auto create index when new collection create.

Is there a way to automatically create index for every new collection?

Comment: Does this help?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

I guess you can create a cron job or just call this method once you create a new collection or whenever you feel you need it.

Comment: I know this information,thank you. ButI don't know whether mongodb have script to  catch collection name or not.

For example, if collection name is test201810, mongo can catch 201810.

Comment: How are you creating new collections?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a js file in which you can write the query to create a collection in `MongoDB` and also `query` for creating an index on it. Finally, you can load the js file with your application or cron.

Comment: I don't know whether mongodb have script to  catch collection name or not.

For example, if collection name is test201810, mongo can catch 201810.